# Estou recebendo None no output

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
    l = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]
num = int(input(print("Choose a number: ")))

new_list = []

for i in l:
    if i < num:
        new_list.append(i)

print(new_list)
```

Estou fazendo esse exercício que pede para digitar um número e imprimir uma nova lista baseada na indicada que tenha todos os valores abaixo do indicado pelo usuário, mas no *output* continua imprimindo `None`, a exemplo:

```
    Choose a number: 
None 8
[1, 1, 2, 3, 5]
```

O que eu estou fazendo errado?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tem um `print()`dentro do `input()` e isso não faz sentido. Assim funciona normal:

```
l = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]
num = int(input("Choose a number: "))
new_list = []
for i in l:
    if i < num:
        new_list.append(i)
print(new_list)
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/B7funW). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/zrcikxiq-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/InputMessage.py).

Comment: Faz sentido, obrigado!